# postgis -ERROR for "enforce_geotype_the_geom"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have one table named **sta**.I wanted to add one more column to it .I did so using following statement:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','station','the_geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

**the_geom** column got added along with following contraints:

```
CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL),
CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4326)
```

I wanted to insert values into **the_geom** column.I tried:

```
update station set the_geom = ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(65.6471666666667  25.0368333333333)');
```

But i am getting error:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "station" violates check constraint "enforce_geotype_the_geom"
```

What does this constraint  mean?How to insert values into the same??

Comment: Every think looks good, but there is a workaround, I'm not posting as answer because its not the right way to do it, but it should work: Declare your geometry type as GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, because the error you are getting is because the type of the data you are updating with, it says is not a POINT, and clearly is point.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the constraint to check the dimensions, geotype and its SRID. The typmod of postgis/postgres already do it for you.

The function `AddGeometryColumn` force the use of typmod (because use_typmod argument is default `true`, as can you see in [addgeometrycolumn documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html).

And, I recommend use the `ALTER TABLE` statement for add a geometry column into the table

```
ALTER TABLE station ADD COLUMN the_geom geometry(Point,4326);
```

And you dont need care for the checks (SRID, geometry type).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why st_geom_fromewkt isn't working but you can try something different like: update station set the_geom=st_setSRID(st_point(65.6471666666667,25.0368333333333), 4326);   That may be a better guarantee of the Point type.